# As I can generate automatic notifications

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am developing an application on android , and I need to receive notifications.

For the type of application that I want , I do not see it necessary internet connection , so I do not require push notifications .

Therefore , I wonder if there is some way that the application automatically generates notifications.

Clarify and not pressing a button , but receive notifications (messages ) in a random time interval .

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create Notifications that launches at a specific time interval. Please do look the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) . You can create `PendingIntent` and use a `BroadcastReceiver` to make a notification at a specific time. Also, do refer [this](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html) guide on creating notifications.